Autograd functions for sparse tensor operations using sksparse.cholmod
I use pytorch.optim to optimize a function which actively uses sparse matrix operations. The current pytorch.sparse package does not support operations like computing Cholesky factorizations of sparse tensors, computing log-determinants or solving sparse linear systems. Therefore it would be very beneficial if I could find some way of implementing these operations as custom autograd functions.
From previous experience, I have found that sksparse.cholmod works very well for sparse Cholesky decomposition of scipy.sparse matrices. This also supports computations of the log-determinant and  can be used to solve systems. I therefore want to use this within my autograd function.
In the following code I have attempted to implement a method for the computation of the log determinant, but there seems to be something wrong with my backwards pass. When I exchange the standard torch.logdet() with my new method compute_log_det the optimization stops converging. For the gradient I have used the result in https://angms.science/doc/LA/logdet.pdf, which states that the gradient of the log-determinant of a symmetric matrix is its inverse.
import torch
import scipy.sparse as sparse
from sksparse.cholmod import cholesky

class LogDetSparse(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, A):
        # Turning the input tensor into a scipy.sparse matrix
        A_dense = A.to_dense().detach()
        A_sparse = sparse.csc_matrix(A_dense.numpy())
        
        # Computing the Cholesky factorization and logdet
        A_chol = cholesky(A_sparse)
        logdet = A_chol.logdet()

        # Saving for use in backward pass
        ctx.A_chol = A_chol

        # Return as a PyTorch tensor
        return torch.tensor(logdet, dtype=A.dtype, device=A.device)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        A_chol = ctx.A_chol

        # Compute the inverse of the original matrix using the Cholesky factorization
        A_inv = A_chol.inv()
        A_inv_tensor = torch.from_numpy(A_inv.toarray()).to(grad_output.device)

        # Compute the gradient
        grad_A = grad_output * A_inv_tensor

        # Convert the gradient to a sparse tensor
        grad_A_sparse = grad_A.to_sparse()

        return grad_A_sparse

def compute_log_det(A):
    return LogDetSparse.apply(A)

Does anybody know what I have done wrong? Is there something wrong with the backwards pass, or could it be something else? Additionally, how can extend the code I have written to also use the Cholesky factorization to solve a system Ax=b?
Alternatively, is there some other way if can do these computations efficiently?
